# Sencha on iOS7 - No ajax exceptions when there is no internet

Tags: javascript, ajax, ios7, sencha-touch

I'm having a bit of an issue getting Sencha Touch to throw an ajax error for iOS7, seems to work fine for Android and used to work on iOS6 (cannot tell for sure yet if it still does).
The code runs when it has internet, but when putting in airplane mode, it'll only work for android.

```
try { 
     Ext.Ajax.request({ 
         url: 'http://google.com',
         async: false,
         timeout: 300,
         cache: false,
         params: {
            method: "test"
         },
         success: onlineFunction
      });
} catch(e) {
     alert("woot! offline!");
}
```

This code seems to work fine in Android as I get the alert, but iOS just decides to ignore all of it.

If all else fails, I'm tempted to just use jQuery instead of Sencha's Ajax function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was provided here: 
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?277178-iOS7-ajax-not-throwing-exceptions&p=1015458&viewfull=1#post1015458

> Check if the device is offline before sending an Ajax request...

```
navigator.onLine
```